# How to bring back Ubuntu after Lion install using rEFIt

Tags: macos, multi-boot, refit, osx-lion

Upgraded to Lion this morning which went mostly smoothly, but when I tried to boot back into Ubuntu (I do most of my work in Linux) I was only able to get as far as the grub command mode.

I spent a good portion of my morning following through guides for similar problems on Windows machines, booting from an Ubuntu install disk and re-installing grub, but I am still unable to boot into my Linux partition.

Comment: It seems rEFIt just doesn't work with Lion *yet*. Do you get any errors reinstalling grub or does it appear to have worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution that was really simple and easy, but resulted in a little bit of data loss.

I had given up on grub after many failed attempts at re-installing from the livecd and was resigned to just reformat the partition and re-install ubuntu, and noticed the option to re-install 11.04 on top of my current copy after starting the installer.

I re-installed, and must have gotten a new copy of grub set up correctly during this step. Only side effect was most of my applications I had installed through the softwarecenter  were missing, but when I re-installed them settings were still there.

After 20 or 30 minutes of re-installing applications rEFIt and both OS installs are working the same way they were before the Lion install.

Answer (score 2):

During my upgrade, I noticed the installer tried to repartition my disk to make space for something.

Maybe it has overwritten your grub stage 1.5, so now you cannot load configuration and drivers; or maybe it changed the relative position of your Linux partition. In these cases, you will probably see grub [rescue mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Command%20Line%20and%20Rescue%20Mode) which takes some guess work to resolve. If it's in normal mode, you can use the `ls` command to find the Linux partition and edit your boot entry accordingly.

An easier way is to use the LiveCD to boot and re-install grub. However, I am not sure if it can install the EFI version of grub for you. You might have to use the MBR version in BootCamp instead.

Comment: The repartition is so a temporary step that the new Lion in place installer takes so it has a partition to run from while making changes to the main OSX partition.

Comment: I checked the partition map last night and it showed a new partition called `Recovery HD` after the main Mac OS X partition, so I guess that's where the new online recovery mode resides...